Docker: ASP.NET Core 8.0 app not accessible outside container
I am struggling to access my ASP.NET Core 8.0 web app (Swagger UI) from outside my container.
Without Docker, it is accessible at the following URL: http://localhost:90/swagger/index.html
I can start the app by executing an .exe file which results in the following output:
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:90
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\Username\Documents\Git\WetterApi\WetterApi

The file structure of my already compiled app looks like following:

Microsoft.OpenApi.dll
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll
WetterApi.deps.json
WetterApi.dll
WetterApi.exe
WetterApi.pdb
WetterApi.runtimeconfig.json
appsettings.Development.json
appsettings.json dockerfile

Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS runtime
COPY . .
EXPOSE 90
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
ENV DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","/WetterApi.dll", "--server.urls","<http://+:90>"]

Building Image:
docker build -t wetter_api_test .

Starting:
docker run --rm -it -p 80:90  wetter_api_test

Port 80 as I want to have it available at http://localhost:80/swagger/index.html outside of the container
Output:
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Overriding address(es) 'http://*:8080'. Binding to endpoints defined via IConfiguration and/or UseKestrel() instead.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:90
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /

Curl on the Container Web App:
curl http://localhost:80/swagger/index.html    
curl : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Does anyone see what exactly I am overlooking or what I do not understand here?
I am thankful for any hint or solution.
Added the following lines to the Dockerfile:
ENV DOTNET_URLS=http://+:90
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:90
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=90

But still, my app is not accessible from outside the container.


Try - Following the Suggestion of Hans Kilian in the comments:

Removed Port Configs in my Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS runtime
COPY . .
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
ENV DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","/WetterApi.dll"]

Running the container with:
docker run --rm -it -p 80:8080  wetter_api_test

Result:
curl http://localhost:80/swagger/index.html
curl : The underlying connection was closed: The 
connection was closed unexpectedly.

When checking the Port Mapping via docker ps everything seems fine to me:
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
2d179c430f50   wetter_api_test   "dotnet /WetterApi.d…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp   gracious_satoshi 


How do u start that container?

@nico_1512: sorry my first draft got flaged as spam. needed to remove the parts. I have edited my post to include (hopefully) all necessary informations.
Starting my container with: docker run --rm -it -p 80:90  wetter_api_test

The log message Now listening on: http://localhost:90 indicates that your app is bound to localhost. That means it will only accept connections from inside the container. Your configuration looks OK though and I would expect it to say Now listening on: http://*:90 or something similar. Try removing all your port configs. Then it should listen on port 8080 and you can then use -p 80:8080 when running it.

@HansKilian thank you for your suggestion. i have removed the port configs of my dockerfile and started the container with -p 80:8080 but still cant access to Web UI inside my container. I have added the section "Try - Following the Suggestion of Hans Kilian in the comments:" to my post for an better overview what exactly i had changed

I suspect there's an issue with your application.
To try to replicate your issue, I made the following Dockerfile based on yours. I've added a build step that creates a template webapi application and then uses your Dockerfile as the runtime step.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 as builder
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet new webapi -n WetterApi -o . && \
    dotnet publish -o app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS runtime
COPY --from=builder /src/app/* .
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
ENV DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","/WetterApi.dll"]

When I build, run and test it with
docker build -t test .
docker run -d -p 80:8080 test
curl http://localhost:80/swagger/index.html

it works as expected.
So I don't think there's anything wrong with your Dockerfile or the way you run it.

Thanks, i will give it a try and create a a simple test project to test this further. I assumed that the issue is my container config as i was able to curl the websit inside of my container by using docker exec

Like I said in my comment earlier, it looks like your issue is that your app binds to localhost. That will cause it to only accept connections from inside the container. Mine, above, binds to all interfaces and accepts connections from outside as well. Since the Dockerfile and the way it's run are the same, the only difference that I can think of, is the application itself.

thank you very much. Can now confirm that indeed the application build was the issue. Solved it there and then i was able to access the Website API of my Docker Container !
